# How to define a property as a map (dictionary)

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, loopback4

I have a loopback model. I want a certain property to have a map type. I tried something like this:

```
  @property({
    postgresql: {
      dataType: 'json',
    }
  })
  nodes: Map<string, string>;
```

or something like this:

```
  @property({
    postgresql: {
      dataType: 'json',
    }
  })
  nodes: {[key: string]: string};
```

It works, but there is no type check and no schema shows up in Swagger api explorer. `nodes` property can have any object or map there, and it's not limited to `<string, string>`

Is there a way for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
import {getJsonSchema} from '@loopback/repository-json-schema'

@model()
export class MapEntry {
  @property()
  id: string;

}

@model( {
  jsonSchema: {
    additionalProperties: getJsonSchema(MapEntry)
  }
})
export class MyMap {
}
```